ubuntu 23.10 blank screen without i915,modest=0 gets balnks screem
I have a mini PC with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1060NG7 CPU @ 1.20GHz processor with Grapics card  Iris Plus Graphics G7 (Ice Lake).
Connected to monitor by HDMI :
If I do not set the I915.modeset to 0 I got black screen only and I can not find anythin in the logs. (Maybe I amy trying to find it at a wrong log.)
If I connect it thru USB hub it works and Kernel driver in use: i915.
What coud be the wrong in the first case. Incase of dierct HDMI.
Thanks
